# Does HUION K58 work with Ubuntu?

Tags: graphics-tablet

So, I am planning to buy HUION K58 which is a pen drawing interface graphics-surface.

[image]

I just want to know does it work with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS without very much tricks? I searched google but I did not find anyone with this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, according to the [DIGImend project](http://digimend.github.io/) the Huion K58 is [supported in Linux kernel versions >=3.11](http://digimend.github.io/tablets/Huion_K58/) which is available in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (I am currently running 3.13.0-43 on Ubuntu 14.04).

Answer (score 1):

I've just bought a K58 and it works perfectly with 12.04 LTS, providing you have up to date kernal (I have 3.13.0-74).